# scikit-learn preperation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the `scikit-learn` package for semi supervised classification, I have a file with classes, instances and features but I am not sure how to prepare this file for `scikit-learn`.  Could you give some guidelines for file preparation?  The tutorial only provide instructions for uploading prepared data sets from machine learning repositories.  Thank you!

Comment: Have you google it first? Have you read the documentation? Try this: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/

Comment: Ok here's a hint. Google something called "RTFM". And after that google "Feature Extraction in sklearn" and "Feature transformation in sklearn". After that come back with more concrete question. This is too vague. And If you already have extracted features (as it's not clear in the question), all you need to do is clf.fit() and clf.predict()

Comment: I am not working with text data, the manual only indicates solutions for text data.  My question is about the input file for scikit learn.  The examples use data iris for example.  My data set is a txt with 50 columns that correspond to numerical features and 2000 rowns that correspond to the samples and there is a column with the class.    digits = datasets.load_digits().  This is used for the data package but my case is not this, this is the reason for my question. thanks

Comment: Please modify the question to describe the data format.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn directly supports special learning-oriented input formats, notably [SVMLight](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/#datasets-in-svmlight-libsvm-format). But in general, its input is a numpy array (when dense), which can be produced from a diverse range of data sources using other tools from the SciPy stack, notably [scipy.io](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/io.html), and more pertinently in the case of a text file with columns, [Pandas IO tools](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/io.html). You can likely use [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/io.html#io-read-csv-table) followed by pulling out, and dropping from the feature set, the target class column.

Comment: Thank you Joein for the information.  I was able to generate a numpy array with the following parameters, but I am not sure if this is the suitable setup,  it would be necessary changes in this parameters?
thedata = np.genfromtxt(
    'unclassSeq_s.txt',          
    skip_header=0,          
    skip_footer=0,          
    delimiter=',',          
    dtype='float32',       
    filling_values=0,      
   
    names=['first', 'second', 'third', 'last'])     # column names
                        
print("\n Printing the data from the csv file.\n")
for row in thedata:
    print(row)

Comment: That will produce a 1-dimensional numpy struct array. You want a 2d non-struct array for scikit-learn input,  plus a separate array for your classes. You can extract that from the struct array `A`, e.g. `X = A[['first', 'second', 'third']]`, `y = A['last']`. But Pandas tends to be more friendly in dealing with these sorts of issues.